# Count only one value for the same date excel

Tags: excel

I need to find out how many days (not times) when temperature have been below -15 degrees.

I have found data from a website that gives me the temperature every half hour but that gives me 48 values for each date.

If the temperature have been below -15 more than one time during the date it should only be counted as one.

Any ideas?

This is my data:

[image: img1]

More example data
[More example data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hY37B.png)

Comment: Can you give a better example of sample data? Where is the temperature, column D? Is it just `3` the whole way down?

Comment: Put `=IF(COUNTIFS(B:B,B2,D:D,"<-15")>0,"Yes","No")` in `E2` and drag down.

Comment: @dwirony that just makes yes/no if the value is above or below -15...

Comment: If the date has any value that is less than -15 at any time, then "Yes" is put on every row for that date. I didn't know if you just wanted a count, or to see WHICH dates were -15 :)

Comment: Ah ok, no I only want one hit for each day that has -15 or below. So if three timestamps gives me -15 it should be counted as 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to your sample image's columns, put this in an unused cell.

```
=SUMPRODUCT((D$2:D$999<=-15)/(COUNTIFS(B$2:B$999, B$2:B$999, D$2:D$999, "<=-15")+(D$2:D$999>-15)))
```

Adjust the rows to your actual data range to minimize calculating blank rows.

Comment: I tried it and just get #Divsion! in the cell... what does <=-45 in your formula do?

Comment: Sorry, that was a typo. It should have been `<=-15`.

Comment: Now it works, it says 70... should be right I guess. Thanks! Any chance you can explain the formula?